# Operators overloading depending on template type and virtual operator

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, virtual

In the following minimal not-working example,
I want to define the operator `<=` by a pure-virtual one `&`. They both take the template type `T` of a template class. I'm wondering how can I correctly defined them.

Here is the example :

:::::::::: A.hpp ::::::::::

```cpp
#ifndef A_HPP
#define A_HPP
#pragma once

#include <vector>

template <typename T> 
class A {

    public:

    template <typename U>
    friend U operator& (const U& lhs, const U& rhs) ;

    // The following operator is defined by the one above
    template <typename U>
    friend bool operator <= (const U& lhs, const U& rhs) ;

    /*** Methods using '&' and '<=' operator ***/
    bool foo(T t1, T t2);
    // ...

    /*** data structures inside class A ***/
    protected:
    std::vector<int> vect;
    // ...

};

#endif // A_HPP
```

`<=` depends on `&`.

:::::::::: A.cpp ::::::::::

```cpp
#include "A.hpp"

template <typename T>
bool operator <= (const T &lhs, const T &rhs)  {
     // Note that the `&` I want use here is the one defined in A.hpp
     if (lhs & rhs) == rhs) return false;
     else return true;
}

// Don't want to define '&' !


template <typename T>
bool A<T>::foo(T t1, T t2) {
    return (true || (t1 <= t2));
}

class AA : public A<bool> {
    public:
    // "override" (friend operator ?) 'meet' operator '&' here with the logic and '&'
    friend bool operator& (const bool& lhs, const bool& rhs) { return lhs & rhs; }
    // inherited '<=' operator
    // ...
};

int main() {
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

## Issues

- The example above doesn't compile because I don't know how to override the `&` operator in class `AA`. It must not be declared as `friend` for overriding, but I can't find another way to define `&` in the base class.
- Moreover, you may be a bit confused, but I've wanted initially to define `A::operator &` as pure-virtual. However, that operator take parameters of type `T` instead of `A`, so I can't declare it as a member operator.
- Why pure-virtual ? Because, I want that inherited classes define `&`
  by themselves (for the first time) and don't want to define `&` in class `A`.

## Idea

I have thought about declaring an inner class which encapsulated `T`, like this :

:::::::::::::: B.hpp ::::::::::::::

```cpp
#ifndef B_HPP
#define B_HPP
#pragma once

#include <vector>

template <typename T> 
class A {


    public:

    class B {
        public:

        B(T t) : value(t) {};

        virtual T operator& (const T& rhs) const = 0 ;
        // The following operator is defined by the one above
        virtual bool operator<= (const T &rhs)  {
            if ((value & rhs) == rhs) return false;
            else return true;
        }
        protected:
        T value;
    };


    /*** Methods using '&' and '<=' operator ***/
    bool foo(B t1, B t2) {
        return (true || (t1 <= t2));
    }
    // ...

    /*** data structure inside Class A ***/
    protected:
    std::vector<int> vect;
    // ...

};

#endif // B_HPP
```

:::::::::::::: B.cpp ::::::::::::::

```cpp
#include "B.hpp"

class AA : public A<bool> {
    public:
    // "override" 'meet' operator '&' here with the logic and '&'
    class B : public A<bool>::B {
        virtual bool operator& (const bool& rhs) { return value & rhs; }
    };
    // inherited '<=' operator
    // ...
};

int main() {
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

Why inner class ? Because take out class `B` from `A` results that `B` is not recognized as a type in method `foo`. And I don't know how to override operators in this case : I'll have a class `BB` inherited from `B<bool>`, declared outside of `AA` and I'll have to tell methods of `AA` that they should use `BB` operators.

Things get very complicated (e.g. this compile with `clang++` but not with `g++`...) and it's beyond of my ability for now as a C++ newbie (10 days).

Comment: Don't use virtual functions.  You are already using templates.

Comment: Everything here is very confused.  Overriding doesn’t mean anything for friend functions, nor does inheritance.  You generally can’t define function templates in source files (unless you have only one!).  Unconstrained templates cause problems for overload resolution; why isn’t it enough for each class to define its own operator, virtual or otherwise?  The (non-standard) `#pragma once` is redundant with the include guards.